# Create service or container from another container, on Google Cloud Run or Cloud Run on GKE

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, knative

Can I create a service or container from another container, on Google Cloud Run or Cloud Run on GKE ?

I basically want to manage my containers/services dynamically from another container and not sure how to go about this

Adding more details:

One of my microservices needs to create new isolated containers that will run some user-land code. I would like to have full life-cycle control of these containers, run the code, and then destroy as needed.

I also looked at Cloud Run APIs but not sure how to run something like 'kubectl create ...' through the APIs? Is that the right approach?

Comment: Could you edit the question to be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sure, why not, just need a pod / container that contains the necessary tools to interact / manage the cluster (i.e. kubectl).

Comment: In summary, you want an on demand environment (serverless) for managing other container? Do you need a terminal access or or only to run scheduled script on it?

Comment: @DougStevenson added some more details to it

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Not sure if I need terminal access at this point, but I wouldn't think so

Comment: Cloud Run (fully managed) does not support DinD. Not sure about Cloud Run on GKE, but I'm pretty unclear why you'd need to do this in a GKE cluster you control.

Comment: @Grayside I'm asking about managing other containers/services on the cluster, not DinD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to deploy Cloud Run services from Cloud Run services.

- on Cloud Run (hosted): services by default run with Editor permissions, so this should be possible without any extra configuration

  - note that if you deploy apps with `--allow-unauthenticated` which requires setting IAM permissions, the Editor role will not be enough, as you need Owner role on the GCP project for that.
- on Cloud Run on GKE: services by default run with limited scopes (as they by default inherit GKE node's permissions/scopes). You should add a service account to the Kubernetes Pod and use it to authenticate.

From there, you have several options:

1. Use the REST API directly: Since `run.googleapis.com` behaves like a Kubernetes API server, you can directly apply JSON objects of Knative Services. (You can use `gcloud ... --log-http` to learn how deployments are made using REST API requests).
2. Use `gcloud`: you can ship your container image with gcloud and invoke it from your process.
3. Use Google Cloud Client Libraries: You can use the client libraries that are available for Cloud Run (for example this [Go library](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/run/v1alpha1)) to construct in-memory Service objects and send them to the API using a higher level client library **(recommended approach)**

Comment: This is great, thank you.

1- Where can I find an example or more info on the first option? 

2- Also, it seems like the first option would be a more standard Knative option that would run the same on every Knative setup? Whereas the third option seems specific to Cloud Run?

3- Lastly, is there a Node library similar to the Go one that you know of ?

Comment: 1. You just write HTTP requests in a http client yourself, just look at --log-http output of gcloud to see what/how it makes such requests. 2. Yeah the Knative API is nearly the same as Cloud Run, but some stuff like authentication will be different. 3. Yes, I'm sure there's a node equivalent library to call Google APIs, like googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client.